# given position in window is white space or element is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to find whether particular coordinate in window is empty or is occupied by any DOM element, if it is empty I need to dynamically add dom element to it.

```js
for(var i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<100;j=j+10)
      {
        var  elem = document.elementFromPoint(i, j);
        console.log(elem.id);
      }
  }
```

```html
<div id="navenn" style="height:100px;background-color:red">
```

The above code will iterate through co ordinates of window, if a position is occupied by any element elem.id should not be empty, but in my case it is always empty

What is x and y parameters in elementFromPoint, does it represent pixels?

Comment: The parameters to `elementFromPoint` represent the coordinates (x and y) in pixels - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're searching coords within the window, `elementFromPoint()` will return an element. You should check to see if it's an element that you've inserted or simply the document `<html>` element.

Below is an example of checking for a particular class:

```js
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 100; y = y + 10) {
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var isItem = elem.classList.contains('item');

    console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y} -  ${isItem ? 'found ' : 'NOT found'}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navenn" class="item" style="height:100px;background-color:red">
```

Here's an example with the `y` coordinate going past 100 (the height of your red `<div>`):

```js
for (var x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < 200; y = y + 10) {
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var isItem = elem.classList.contains('item');

    console.log(`x: ${x}, y: ${y} -  ${isItem ? 'found ' : 'NOT found'}`);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="navenn" class="item" style="height:100px;background-color:red">
```